# What to do when you are out of healing items in DeathSpank inside a mine?

Tags: deathspank

**SPOILER WARNING**

---

I was playing DeathSpank and an annoying thing happened to me. I descended into Demon Mine near Pluckmuckel village and finally reached the boss, but I died several times (it was 4 levels more than me), and used all my potions and other health recovery items in the attempt.

Then I decide to take a break, I exit and when I re-entered the game later, all demons were respawned. I tried to return to the Village using teleports but they were not working, so it took me a lot of time and dozens of deaths to finally exit from the cave because when you die you respawn with very low health.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: This very situation is one of the cases where Sparkles' healing power comes in handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a bug and is working as intended. The outhouses inside dungeon-like areas are intended to be "out of order." They're only there to serve as respawn points inside the mine; they can't be used to teleport into the main outhouse network. I'm assuming you're talking about the Nanny Demon, which is mentioned in a question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3461/how-do-i-defeat-the-nanny-demon-in-deathspank) if you want any tips about it for a future replay. DeathSpank is a hack-and-slash game, so it's intended that enemies respawn after reloading the game (and they respawn after a certain period of time even if you don't).

Depending on how many sidequests you have done already, you may be making a few more trips into those mines. Here are some general tips:

- Before you head in, **buy some potions from Bong**. It's always good to have some in case of an emergency.
- **Break open barrels!** I did this constantly as I played and it kept me decently stocked on heal-over-time food items. The food items you get from barrels auto-level with you, so when you're lower level, you'll get Pizzas, and it'll scale up through French Fries, Milkshakes, and Hamburgers automatically as you get higher.
- If you're impatient, you can **buy some food from Juan the food vendor**. He's just outside of Pluckmuckel. He only sells lower level food, but it's pretty cheap, and will still be useful for you if you're still around level 11.
- **Kill chickens!** If all else fails, you can fall back on your supply of drumsticks. I had to do this once when I was stuck somewhere without any other food items. They don't heal very much at all after you're higher level (I had to eat like, 20 or something) but they'll do in a pinch if you really need them.
- **Don't forget to block!** If you need to really just run through somewhere, hold down Block and when it decays, hit the Block button again. Rinse, repeat. Additionally, learning the timing for a Perfect Block will really help you throughout the game. It'll automatically fill your Justice Meter, letting you unleash your special attack. Take a moment when you encounter new enemies to watch their attack pattern so you can do this.

The boss is dead though and will not respawn, so mostly, your future trips into the mines should be pretty painless. Good luck, fellow Dispenser of Justice!

Comment: Thank you, wise man, for your detailed answer. Next time I will bring a Dispenser of Chickens with me, DeathSpank will not fail anymore! :)

Comment: @Drake, you're welcome, o Hero of the Downtrodden, though I'm a woman. ;) Don't be shy about just mass slaughtering chickens wandering around for more drumsticks. every time I warped back into Pluckmuckel, I'd kill the ones around the outhouse on my way to the stores/quest turnins. You can carry a max of 99.Good luck vanquishing evil!